# Understanding javascript simple module behavior

Tags: javascript, methods, module

I have created a simple module returning an object. Since i'm using a closure here, why is the variable jow = undefined with this code:

```
var test = (function(){

    var jow = "x";

    return {

        returnJow:function(jow){alert("the return = " + jow)}

    }



})();

test.returnJow();
```

If i remove the jow parameter on the returnJow method i do get "the return = x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In direct answer to your question: Yes.

("If i remove the jow parameter on the returnJow method i do get "the return = x".")

```
var test = (function(){
    var jow = "x";
    return {
        returnJow:function(jow){alert("the return = " + jow)}
    }
})();

test.returnJow(); //"the return = undefined"
```

now, lets use jow from the test closure

```
var test = (function(){
    var jow = "x";
    return {
        returnJow:function(){alert("the return = " + jow)}
    }
})();

test.returnJow(); //"the return = x"
```

Or, we can pass jow into the function...

```
var test = (function(){
    var jow = "x";
    return {
        returnJow:function(jow){alert("the return = " + jow)}
    }
})();

test.returnJow("x"); //"the return = x"
```

Or, better still.. we can use the jow in the closure if we don't pass anything into returnJow()...

```
var test = (function(){
    var jow = "x";
    return {
        returnJow:function(new_jow){
            var jow = new_jow !== undefined ? new_jow : jow;
            alert("the return = " + jow);
        }
    }
})();

test.returnJow(); //"the return = x"
test.returnJow("hello"); //"the return = hello"
```

Missed one off:

we can also declare test as an object literal, seeing as we're not passing any information into the closure:

```
var test = {
    jow: "x",
    returnJow: function(new_jow) {
            var jow = new_jow !== undefined ? new_jow : this.jow;
            alert("the return = " + jow);
        }
};

test.returnJow(); //"the return = x"
```

Helpful?

Answer (score 2):

You declare `returnJow` as a `function(jow)`, as a function expecting an argument "jow". Inside the function, `jow` refers to the argument, not to the previously declared variable.

`test.returnJow()` misses the argument `jow`, therefore it is undefined.

Comment: Ok, clear... i thought that, if no argument was passed, it would look up the local jow variable and return it's value.

Answer (score -1):

Oh Sry i had a mistake.
this is worked sure !

```
var test = function(){
    jow: "x",
    returnJow:function(jow){alert("the return = " + test.jow)}
};

test.returnJow();
```

Comment: This code is why I want to throw large livestock at the heads of people who say _In javascript, everything is an object_. In Javascript, everything is an object **unless it's a block**, oh and btw, object literals and blocks share the same notation. Go have fun!